# Replace matching START END lines

Tags: regex, shell, perl, awk, sed

I am trying to replace two matching patterns on multiple lines, replace only the matching `start` and `end` lines and keep the lines between `start` and `end`.

I tried to combine some answers from here using sed, awk, Python, Perl but no luck.

This is what I have:

````
other text

```term
command1
```

other text

```term
command1
command2
```

other text

```js
code
```
````

The replaced text should look like this:

````
other text

{{< terminal >}}
command1
{{< /terminal >}}

other text

{{< terminal >}}
command1
command2
{{< /terminal >}}

other text

```js
code
```
````

Basically I want to replace each matching par of lines that include `` term  with `{{< terminal >}}` and `` with `{{< /terminal >}}`.

I can't do a simple search and replace the lines containing the `start` and `end` patterns because `end` can match other `start` lines which I want to keep.

Comment: Sorry but it is not clear, could you please post more clear examples of samples in your question and let us know then?

Comment: Basically I want to replace each matching par of lines that include ``` term  with `{{< terminal >}}` and  ```  with {{< /terminal >}}.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you please try following.

````
awk -v start="{{< terminal >}}" -v end="{{< /terminal >}}" '
/```/ && found==""{
  if(rest_of_values){
    print rest_of_values
    rest_of_values=""
  }
  found=1
  val1=$0
  next
}
/```/ && found==1{
  print start ORS rest_of_values ORS end
  rest_of_values=found=""
  next
}
{
  rest_of_values=(rest_of_values?rest_of_values ORS:"")$0
}
END{
  if(rest_of_values){
    print val1 ORS rest_of_values
  }
}
'  Input_file
````

***What does code take care of:***

- It looks for pairs of ``` string and if a pair is FOUND then only it changes its values.
- In case a pair is NOT completed then it prints the values of those lines as it is too(without changed lines basically).

***Explanation:*** Adding a detailed explanation for above code here.

````
awk -v start="{{< terminal >}}" -v end="{{< /terminal >}}" '      ##Starting awk program from here with variable values start and end here.
/```/ && found==""{                                               ##Checking condition if ``` is found in a line and variable found is NULL then do following.
  if(rest_of_values){                                             ##Checking condition if variable rest_of_values is NOT NULL then do following.
    print rest_of_values                                          ##Print variable rest_of_values here.
    rest_of_values=""                                             ##Nullifying variable rest_of_values here.
  }                                                               ##Closing BLOCK for above if condition here.
  found=1                                                         ##Setting variable found variable value as 1 here.
  val1=$0                                                         ##Setting variable val1 value as current line value here.
  next                                                            ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}                                                                 ##Closing BLOCK for /```/ && found==""{ condition here.
/```/ && found==1{                                                ##Checking condition if ``` is found and variable found is NOT NULL then do following.
  print start ORS rest_of_values ORS end                          ##Printing value of variable start,ORS,rest_of_values,ORS and end variable here.
  rest_of_values=found=""                                         ##Nullifying variables rest_of_values and found here.
  next                                                            ##next will skip all further statements frmo here.
}                                                                 ##Closing BLOCK for condition /```/ && found==1{ here.
{
  rest_of_values=(rest_of_values?rest_of_values ORS:"")$0         ##If above both conditions are NOT matching then creating a variable rest_of_values, keep concatenating its own value each time it comes here.
}
END{                                                              ##Starting END BLOCK for this awk program here.
  if(rest_of_values){                                             ##Checking condition if variable rest_of_values is NOT NULL then do following.
    print val1 ORS rest_of_values                                 ##Printing values val1 ORS rest_of_values here.
  }
}                                                                 ##Closing BLOCK for END BLOCK of this awk code here.
'  Input_file                                                     ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
````

Comment: Thanks! I only had to change the first matching ```  to ```term and remove the "val1 ORS" part.

Answer (score 3):

perl version :

````
while (<>){
    if  (/```term/ ... /```/){
        if  (/```term/){
            print "{{< terminal >}}\n";
            next;
        } elsif (/```/) {
            print "{{< /terminal >}}\n";
            next;
        }
    }
    print;
}
````

command to run :

```
perl test.pl input-file
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

````
sed -i '/^```term/{s//{{< terminal >}}/;:a;n;/^```/!ba;s//{{< \/terminal >}}/}' file
````

Search for a line beginning ```` ```term ```` ,replace it by `{{< terminal >}}` continue fetching and printing lines until one that begins ```` ``` ```` and replace it by `{{< /terminal >}}`. All other lines print as normal.

Comment: Thanks! This solution works without any side effects.

Answer (score 1):

Just try this:(`Nested START END doesn't work and there is no sample/question also`)

````
$str=~s/((\`\`\`)term)((?:(?!\2).)*)(\2)/\{\{< terminal >\}\}$3\{\{<\/ terminal>\}\}/gs;

   ((\`\`\`)term) #  Start match ```term
   ((?:(?!\2).)*)#  Not equal to ```
   (\2)#  End Match```
````